# Catch exception during scp using Python

Tags: python, exception

I am using `os.system("echo y | pscp.exe -q -i key.ppk file.txt server_location")` which works fine. I want to be able to catch exceptions when the transfer fails for some reason. Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

os.system() return value depends on operating system. On POSIX and possibly on some Windows this would work:

```
retval = os.system(command)
print "command return value is %d" % (retval >> 8)
```

There are no exceptions to handle there, just the shell return value. The bit shift is there because someone thought it would be useful to return multiple things in one variable (the first 8 bits are the signal that killed the command).

You might want to look at the subprocess module instead of os.system() though: It gives you more control (including an exception on non-zero return value if you use `subprocess.check_call()` or `subprocess.check_output()` even if it's not very useful: you still need to check the shell return value to see what the problem was).

Comment: `child_traceback` is a helpful one also for subprocess.

Comment: Unfortunately the return value is the same i.e. zero, either if the file is transferred successfully as well as if the server is offline and no connection is established.

Answer (score 0):

While the below should work, [read about os.system() and os.wait() here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html)

```
import os
import sys

# Saving os.system return_value
# See explanation for os.system(), os.wait() regarding the 2 different bytes received

ret_val = os.system( command )

# Exiting with ret_val, after shifting the lower irrelevant 8 bits
# (the lower 8 bits of os.wait() is the kill signal for the command )

sys.exit( ret_val >> 8 )
```